# Architectural advice: How to synchronize SignalR messages with the backend?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-web-api, signalr

First I want to describe the scenario:

- Let's say I have an admin page where multiple different things are displayed.
- The things displayed are sent by client devices (SignalR between admin <-> clients).
- Clients can see what other clients send.
- They can like this stuff.
- Likes have an effect to the order of items on the admin side.

---

Everything that is send across SignalR has to be saved in the database (can be done async) for the simple reason when somebody refreshes the site (initial page load).

**Admin side**

At first I wanted to do my own polling with a 5s interval (ASP.NET Web API).
But that's not real time and that's not what I call good performance (the db is queried every time).
Now my problem is to make sure that the received items via SignalR from the clients are in sync with the database.
And also the order has to match. So I have to replicate a little of the business logic concerning the likes/votes in JavaScript and on and on.

This seems prone to errors.

What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a lib that fits very good when you want to catch events fired in backend and forward them to clients. Please see my answer here

[How to use a Singleton Signalr client within an MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197274/how-to-use-a-singleton-signalr-client-within-an-mvc-application/21204600#21204600)

[Refreshing List of news using SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142379/refreshing-list-of-news-using-signalr/21157002#21157002)